# blueimp jquery file upload issues on ie9

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, blueimp

having "issues" with the blueimp jquery file uploader, uploads fine, but no progress is reported back to the calling page, only in ie8/ie9.

"done" seems to work properly, its only the "progress" part that isnt working, anyone any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('#video').fileupload({
             forceIframeTransport: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                    $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
                    alert(file);
                    $('input#upload_video').val(file.name);
                    $('p#filename').text(file.name+ ' Uploaded');
                    $('input#video').remove();

                    alert( $('input#upload_video').val());

                });
            },

            progress: function (e, data) {

                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('p#filename').text('Please wait...' +progress + '%');
            },

            start: function (e) {
                // alert('Uploads started');
            },

            stop: function (e) {
                // alert('Uploads finished');
            },

            fail: function (e, data) {
                alert('Your video could not be uploaded');
                $('p#filename').text('');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It's just not supported in IE at the moment.
See https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1369

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not support XMLHttpRequest level 2, so you won't be able to have progress working with IE < 10. It does not have anything related with the plugin.

http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Answer (score -3):

```
    $("#txt1").fileupload({
        replaceFileInput: false,
        dataType: "json",        
        datatype:"json",
        url: "<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/WebService/AddAttachment.ashx")%>",
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, value) {
         //You get the response data in here from your web service
            })
            $("#txt1").val("");
        }`enter code here`
    });
```

This is tested and working fine in both IE8 and IE9 + above. Please make sure to use the correct dataType:"json" (or datatype:"json") and also make sure your response of web service method is correctly updated to data.result when you debug and check.
Thanks